# weighted mean across rasters in R

Tags: raster, r

I have 2 rasters. One raster (bio1) contains temperature information across a continent. The other (sp) contains, for each cell, a probability of occurrence for a species. I would like to calculate the average temperature across the continent, where the average is weighted according to the probability values for each cell.

Any ideas?

```
sp<-raster(ncol=12,nrow=6)
sp[]<-c(0.3659248,0.3251995,0.3263240,0.4835116,0.6494138,0.5220696,0.4151727,0.6915647,0.5147048,0.2470879,0.2054283,0.1863406,0.2673065,0.2962143,0.2796624,0.4613542,0.4592576,0.2794486,0.2651766,0.4326347,0.3203363,0.2654715,0.1993542,0.2030421,0.2529734,0.2539935,0.2607953,0.2750939,0.2666969,0.2316632,0.2347576,0.2307931,0.2251635,0.2262545,0.1979716,0.1856529,0.2378655,0.2322828,0.2469152,0.2390453,0.2385228,0.2264184,0.2275306,0.2265828,0.2102648,0.2297261,0.1984145,0.1980131,0.2277406,0.2315173,0.2225589,0.2391843,0.2375292,0.2271611,0.2050888,0.2188710,0.2208964,0.2017645,0.1957584,0.1824360,0.2086336,0.2104096,0.2153448,0.2204493,0.2174766,0.2268214,0.2246680,0.1954685,0.1959728,0.2130131,0.1927875,0.1941573)

bio1<-raster(ncol=12,nrow=6)
bio1[]<-c(257,264,262,234,207,225,238,194,220,262,267,267,259,266,266,236,236,262,265,234,252,258,267,267,268,267,265,265,266,267,267,267,267,266,267,267,267,267,267,267,266,267,267,267,266,264,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,266,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267,267)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure that there is a "memory safe" way to do this but you can just call the raster values in the weighted.mean function in base.

```
weighted.mean(x=values(bio1), w=values(sp), na.rm=TRUE)
```